# What is the probe comp signal on a Keysight DSOX2004A?

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

I was trying to measure a WS2812 signal on my Keysight DSOX2004A oscilloscope. The signal didn't look right for one probe. The rectangular signal looked undercompensated. Sure enough, I know that probes can be compensated and I know how to do it. I connected the probe to the "Probe comp" port and made sure it outputs a nice rectangle waveform.

It was still not triggering the way I expected on the WS2812 signal, but it triggered nicely on the probe comp signal. I was wondering what the specifications of the Probe compensation signal are. I tried looking it up in the manual (ninth edition Feb 2018 and [thirteenth edition June 2022](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/9018-03426/user-manuals/9018-03426.pdf)).

The manual mentions "Probe comp" in both versions of the manual:

- on page 29 (chapter "Input a waveform"), without giving specifications
- on page 31 (chapter "Auto scale"), without giving specifications
- on page 32 (chapter "Compensating passive probes"), without giving specifications
- on page 39 (chapter "Getting started"), without giving specifications

Questions:

- Is it normal to not know the frequency and voltage of the probe compensation signal?
- How would you check something if you don't know what you're measuring?
- Am I just searching for the wrong term?
- What *is* the test signal of the DSOX2004A?

The frequency of 1 kHz looks right, but the voltage of 2.6 V doesn't. I expected 1 volt.

Other oscilloscopes seem to write it near the "Cal" port, like this 1Vp-p 1Khz (sorry for the bad quality, found this online):

[image: Kenwood Cal port]

I also tried:

- searching for "1 kHz", which brings me to page 255 (chapter "Waveform generator defaults")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it normal to not know the frequency and voltage of the probe
> compensation signal?*

Page 31 of this manual: [Keysight InfiniiVision
2000 X-Series Oscilloscopes](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/DSOX20xxa-ug.pdf) shows you what to expect: -

[image]

> *The frequency of 1 kHz looks right, but the voltage of 2.6 V doesn't.
> I expected 1 Volt.*

Not according to the picture on page 31. It looks like 2.6 volts p-p to me at 1 kHz. Maybe my manual is different to yours. Unfortunately I have to log-in to Keysight to see the manual you are trying to link.

Comment: Okay, I didn't expect that I need to read that information from the picture, but yes, that's close.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes it's close and it does surprise me that there isn't a written spec.

Comment: It looks more like 2.55 Vpp with 0.1V of noise and 0 V low level.

Answer (score 0):

The actual frequency and amplitude of the square wave is not that important.

The most important function is to use it for calibrating probe compensation.

Sure if you know that it is say 1V, you can also use it for making sure that your probe and/or scope are set to 1x or 10x setting properly, so readings on the screen are 1V, instead of 0.1V or 10V.

Answer (score 0):

I may have been overthinking a solution before digesting your issue.

Your question : what is probe comp signal? Simply a low frequency square wave & nothing special.

Your issue: unable to trigger WS2812 signal properly on a high-end Tek DSO.

Analysis: LED stripleds with WS2812’s act as transmission line repeaters so there is no common ground and any node other than source will have noise.  Thus differential probe methods are needed when Common mode noise is an issue and/or using the 20 MHz option may be needed to attenuate peak ground noise spikes.

- the differential logic probes will work best with a programmed threshold.
- Also twin probes Ch1-Ch2 mode, or design your own diff board or use expensive FET diff probes.